# Load-balancing multiple topic subscriptions across nodes of cluster

Tags: java, load-balancing, distributed-computing, publish-subscribe, apache-zookeeper

Our application subscribes to a list of topics and these topics can add/removed dynamically. We plan to have cluster of such application nodes so that each node can subscribe to distinct set of topics; similar to load-balancing subscriptions across nodes in cluster. We can't have same topic subscription on more than one node as we need to avoid duplicate processing of same message across nodes.

Is there any solution to achieve below:

1. If we have to subscribe to a new topic, the node which has lesser
   load (less topic subscriptions) will subscribe to this topic.
2. When a node goes offline, all its topics will be subscribed by other nodes active in the cluster.

Can Zookeeper be used for this purpose to co-ordinate this information across nodes?

Answer (score 0):

Try to make a load balancer application which will do the operation of load balancing and it should be connected to both nodes. It will do regular health check up of both the nodes and forward the subscription request in round robin fashion. If a node goes down then it will get intimated by regular health check up and then it will forward the subscription request to one single connected node. You can use Netty API for making load balancer which uses TCP/IP connectivity.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Zookeeper can be used to implement this logic. Take a look at the Apache Helix Rabbit MQ recipe which does something similar.

http://helix.apache.org/0.6.4-docs/recipes/rabbitmq_consumer_group.html

This explains the logic for a single topic. Helix distributes the topics/partitions across all nodes in the cluster. If you want to restrict the nodes to which the partitions get distributed, you can tag the resource and nodes accordingly.
For e.g If you have node A, B, C, D, E, F

If you want topic T1,T2 to be only on A and B, you can tag A and B as X and also tag the Resources T1 and T2 in Helix as X. Helix will ensure that T1 and T2 will only be subscribed by A and B.

Note: A node/instance in Helix can have multiple tags. 1 and 2 should be automatically handled by Helix